# How to create a random mask array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I've an array with 128 values, each value is 1:

```
length = 128
partials = Array.new length

partials.each_index do |i|
    partials[i] = 1
end
```

I want to set value 0 on some (random) position (for example, on pos 1,6,50,70,100,112,120).

Of course, the number of position could be different every time, and if I choose 7 different position, I want to end with 7 different pos changed.

What's the faster way to do this in Ruby?

Comment: Why not simply use the Random class? http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Random.html

Comment: Working from @Aziuth's comment: `7.times{partials[rand(128)]=0}}`

Comment: I guess you want to know from someone with experience _the_ fastest way.

Comment: You have to make clear what you want. What is "some position"? Do you already know how many 0's you want, or do you want that to be random as well? Do you want all possible patterns (2*128 patterns) to have the same occurrence probability? etc.

Comment: Are you saying that you want a method `rnd_arr`, invoked `rnd_arr(n,z)`, that returns an array containing `z` zeroes and `n-z` ones such that the positions of the zeroes (and therefore the ones) are randomized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way:

```
array = 128.times.map{1}
```

Or with randomly sprayed 0s:

```
array = 128.times.map{rand(2)}
```

or put a number of 0s later:

```
10.times{array[rand(128)]=0}
```

etc... Play with it and see what you need

Comment: You can also pass a block to `Array.new`, e.g. `Array.new(128) { rand(2) }`

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want to have `n` elements with value `0`, you can do the below:

```
n = 5
partials[0,n] = [0]*n
partials.shuffle
```

---

Alternatively, can also be written as:

```
partials.tap{|p| p[0,n] = [0]*n}.shuffle
```

Answer (score 4):

You can incorporate the zeros into the array creation:

```
length = 128
zeros = 7
partials = Array.new(length) { |i| i < zeros ? 0 : 1 }.shuffle
#=> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
#    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
#    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
#    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
#    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
#    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
#    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
#    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: A variant: `([1]*(length-zeroes)).concat([0]*zeroes).shuffle`.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
length = 10
zeros = 2

([0]*(length-zeros)+[1]*zeros).shuffle
```